# How do I modify this Client class to read input from an array of Strings (rather than from standard input)?

Tags: java, static, bufferedreader

I have the following code, in a Java Client class ( it's this [KnockKnock client/server pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) ) :

```
   try {
      kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
      out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
      in =  KKJokes[0]; //new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
      // in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    }
```

I want to have it automatically  read from a String array (that contains all those predefined Jokes ) , something like this :

```
       String KKJokes[] =  {"Who's there?", "Turnip who?", 
           "y", "Who's there?", "Who's there?", "blah" };
        /* more cod */
       try {
          kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
          out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

       for (int i = 0; i< KKJokes.length; i++) {
          in =  new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( KKJokes[i] )) ; 
       }
      }
```

But this doesn't work, it gives :

```
KnockKnockClientRedux.java:33: non-static variable KKJokes cannot be referenced from a static context
      for (int i = 0; i< KKJokes.length; i++) {
                         ^ KnockKnockClientRedux.java:34: non-static variable KKJokes cannot be referenced from a static context
      in =  new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( KKJokes[i] )) ; //new Buf feredReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
                                                       ^ KnockKnockClientRedux.java:34: cannot find symbol symbol  : constructor InputStreamReader(java.lang.String) location: class java.io.InputStreamReader
      in =  new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( KKJokes[i] )) ; //new Buf feredReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
```

EDIT:  Wouldn't it be easier to just read from a text file? Maybe I'll list all the KnockNock joke lines vertically in a text file. That way, it seems easier to swap in a `FileReader` for the `kkSocket.getInputStream()` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler message tells it all. Try with

```
static String KKJokes[] =  {"Who's there?", "Turnip who?", 
       "y", "Who's there?", "Who's there?", "blah" };
```

The second problem can be solved with:

```
new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayInputStream(KKJokes[i].getBytes() )
```

Comment: This fixes part of it, thanks ! I still have the `KnockKnockClientRedux.java:34: cannot find symbol symbol  : constructor InputStreamReader(java.lang.String) location` tho

Comment: Try with:
new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayInputStream(KKJokes[i].getBytes() )